# In Javascript (Node.js), Is It Possible To Pass an Already Instantiated Class Object into Another Code Module

Tags: node.js

I'm probably missing a larger point of Javascript here, but I wanted to ask the community if the answer is 'NO!'.

Let's say you have an index.js that requires a udp port module:

index.js:

```
let port1 = require(udp_port.js);

port1.start( { port: 1234, classObj: new myClassObj() } );
```

udp_port.js:

```
let dgram = require('dgram');

let msgProcessor; // This is the class obj I'm trying to pass in from index.js

let server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

exports.start = function(configObj) {


   msgProcessor = configObj.classObj; // Can I do this???

}
```

Any advice would be great at this point, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly possible to pass parameters.  What don't you understand?

Comment: Integers and Strings absolutely, but can you pass in a class object? Something you instantiated with the keyword 'new'?

Comment: Yes, you can pass anything. Why don't you execute your code and test if it works or not? Although it should..

Comment: There is nothing special about objects that make parameters not work.

Comment: Out of curiosity did you try running said code before posting? It would've probably been an easier (and quicker) way to discover the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Javascript (Node.js), Is It Possible To Pass an Already Instantiated Class Object into Another Code Module

Yes, it is perfectly possible to pass an instantiated object created in one module to another module.  That is done all the time.

> Integers and Strings absolutely, but can you pass in a class object? Something you instantiated with the keyword 'new'?

Yes, something instantiated with `new` can be passed.  There are no limitations on what you can pass.  Any Javascript type of data.  Separate modules loaded into the same nodejs program all run in the same Javascript interpreter.  There are no limitations at all on how they can share data with each other.

Comment: Yep, I had code that I ran before posting but saw mixed results. The code I put in this post was code I cut out of my program. I ended up solving the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

@James Yep, I had code that I ran before posting but saw mixed results. The code I put in this post was code I cut out of my program. I ended up solving the problem though. What I thought was a limitation of passing variables, was actually a problem related to globals inside a container module (that the instantiated class object was getting passed into).

I was declaring multiple container variables and the global inside was getting reassigned/overwrote with each instantiated class object I passed in.

port1.start(...);
port2.start(...);

had 'msgProcessor' getting assigned twice. Yikes!